# .Net Core querying records from different microservices

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, microservices, serverless-architecture

I'm learning how to design and implement microservices using serverless technologies.  I'm trying to create autonomous microservices and am having difficulty understanding how to communicate data across/between microservices.  I'm using .Net Core for my microservices and am wanting each microservice to be a AWS lambda function exposed via API Gateway.

I have the following scenario:

1. **Institution microservice** - returns a list of institutions within a radius (25 miles) of a zipcode.
2. **ROI Calculator microservice** - receives a zip code as input and calls *institution microservice* receiving a list of institutions.  For each institution returned, perform a series of calculations yielding a ROI value.

How should *ROI Calculator microservice* make a call to institution microservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET core web api application can be published as it is on AWS Lambda as Serverless function. You get everything that regular .NET core application provides like controllers , models etc. Amazon API gateway proxy is integrated directly into .NET Core api routing system. So your AWS lambda function will be serving your .Net core web api. You should watch this tutorial for starters to get better understanding.

[Create .NET Core AWS lambda function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhEANj3Y6ZQ)

**.NET core AWS Lambda Microservices**

If you go by template provided by AWS SDK (ASP.NET core web api template) and you publish .Net core web api on AWS it will configure everything for you including AWS Lambda function and API gateway. So if you have create 2 .net core web api projects you will have 2 web api gateways. The problem is if we have 10 microservices mean we will have 10 api gateways , so we should ideally have 1 api gateway for multiple microservices.

I have worked on POC recently that has one API gateway and all microservices AWS lambda functions are behind this. Each microservice has base path e.g. shopping or users setup in their startup.cs that will identify them individually behind apigateway. so microservice 1 will be **apigateway/shopping/{anything}** , another microservice will be **apigateway/users/{anything}** and they both are configured behind api gateway. API Gateway will send request to AWS lambda function (.Net core web api) and this request will be resolved by .Net core routing system. Even multiple controller can be used this way in a single web api project without problem.

I have modified serverless.template so we can only publish aws lambda function and configure apigateway seperatley. You can find code sample and details on my github blog here [.NET Core Web API AWS Lambda Microservices Sample](https://github.com/ImranMA/CodeSamples/tree/master/DotNetCore-AWSLambda-Microservices) .

Comment: how do you handle scenario where you need your users microservice to consume data from your shopping microservice?

Comment: You will go through API Gateway to query the data

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this depending on your independance of the microservices is probably the best answer:

1. Make a internal HTTP call from the ROI -> Institution which would be okay. The problem with this is that if the service is down the data will not be available.
2. Store the data needed to make the calculation inside the ROI service as well. This seems strange but the data once created in say the Institution service it could be sent via a message bus to the ROI service which then uses the data when needed. (this however may not suit your domain, it depends what information it needs).

However it seems that the calculation and the storage of the Institutions could be within the same microservice therefore eleminating the problem.